# Reference to the this pointer: GCC vs clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, this-pointer

This is a follow-up of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446854/why-gcc-5-3-0-gives-warning-when-binding-reference-to-this-pointer#comment66215826_39446854) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258248/is-it-possible-to-get-reference-to-this-pointer-in-class-body-without-using-th).

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
private:
    A* const& this_ref{this};
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    (void)a;
}
```

If compiled with the `-Wextra`, both [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/TYQ75w) v6.2 and [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/hB8d3p) v3.9 show a warning.

Anyway, with the slightly modified version shown below they behave differently:

```
struct A {
    A* const& this_ref{this};
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    (void)a;
}
```

In this case [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/eeXFrR) doesn't give any warning, [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/wk9B0h) gives the same warning as returned in the previous example.

The warnings are almost the identical.
It follows the one from clang:

> 3 : warning: binding reference member 'this_ref' to a temporary value [-Wdangling-field]

Which compiler is right?

I would say that GCC is wrong in this case and I were opening an issue, but maybe it's the opposite because of an arcane corner case of the language.

Comment: The two examples seem identical. Also you failed to present the warning.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Difference is `private:`. But showing the actual warnings would be good indeed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The examples differ for the `private` and I'm going to add the warning for you are right indeed.

Comment: @hyde Added the warning. Thank you.

Comment: The truly weird bit is that this connects two unrelated parts of the language. `private:` is a name lookup restriction, and here it applies to the name lookup of  `this_ref`. The temporary value is `this`, but it isn't used in a context where the name `this_ref` must be looked up.

Comment: @skypjack: European keyboard layout, the backtick \` is also used to place accents on vowels. E.g. à. But fixed now.

Comment: @MSalters I'm from Italy. I'm used to using those keyboards indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this warning is IMO this excerpt from standard (12.2.5):

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the
>   constructor exits.

and since the [keyword this is a prvalue expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this), during `this_ref` initialization a temporary will be created and `this_ref` is bound to that temporary.

But I have doubt whether your reference is actually initialized in `ctor-initializer`.

If you write:

```
struct A {
private:
    const int& rr = 1+1;
};
```

then you will reproduce the exact same problem with gcc, removing private will also remove this warning.

From what I know `this pointer` might be used in the body of the non-static member function, I have never read that it could be used as argument during default member initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The member declaration

```
A* const& this_ref{this};
```

binds a reference to a temporary that only exists during constructor execution (note: `this` is an rvalue expression).

I'm not sure if `this` is formally available in that context, but if it is then with any use of that pointer you have serious case of UB.

Re

> **”** Which compiler is right?

… a compiler can issue as many diagnostics as it wants. It's not wrong to issue a diagnostic. So per your description, that both accept the code, then either both compilers are right (which I think is most likely), or both are wrong.

Comment: They both issue the warning in one case, but they do not in the other case. I can accept that diagnostics are for free, but here there is a lack of coherence at least.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), and [temporary object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) will be created when binding reference to a prvalue, so you're binding reference member to a temporary in [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

And binding reference member to temporary in default member initializer is ill-formed, which is stated by the standard explicitly.

[$12.6.2/11 Initializing bases and members
[class.base.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#11):

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member from a default
>   member initializer is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A() = default;          // OK
>   A(int v) : v(v) { }     // OK
>   const int& v = 42;      // OK
> };
> A a1;                     // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
> A a2(1);                  // OK, unfortunately
> ```
>
> — end example ]

And see [CWG 1696](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1696), this is applied to C++14.